# How to reset the wizard inside a modal to initial state

Tags: telerik, telerik-mvc

Is there a way, after the user clicks the complete button that all the information
in the wizard is set back to the default.

I have a modal to add users with 2 wizard steps and a complete step. The complete step has two buttons 1)to start the process again 2)to close the modal. After complete everything in the modal is being reset to initial state and if I reopen the modal it always displays the complete step.

```
<telerik:RadWizard RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="AddUserWizard" runat="server" Skin="MetroTouch" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad" OnClientButtonClicking="OnClientButtonClicking"  DisplayProgressBar="False" DisplayNavigationButtons="True">
<WizardSteps>
    <telerik:RadWizardStep ID="SearchUserStep" Title="Select User" runat="server" StepType="Start">
        <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadCodeBlock4" runat="server">
            <div id="userSearchDiv">
                <ul>
                    <li>Users</li>
                    <li>Groups</li>
                </ul>
                <div id="tabuserSearch" >
                    <input id="UserSearchTxt" type="text" />
                    <img src='images/magnifier.gif' style='vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;' alt='Click here to search' border="0" onclick='searchUser();' />
                </div>
                <div id="tabGroupSearch" >
                    <input id="GroupSearchTxt" type="text" />
                    <img src='images/magnifier.gif' style='vertical-align: middle; cursor: pointer;' alt='Click here to search' border="0" onclick='searchGroup();' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
    </telerik:RadWizardStep>
    <telerik:RadWizardStep ID="edituser" Title="Edit User" runat="server" StepType="Finish">
        <iframe id="editUserFrame" src="" frameborder="0" style="width: 100%; height: 360px;"></iframe>
    </telerik:RadWizardStep>
    <telerik:RadWizardStep runat="server" StepType="Complete" CssClass="complete" >
    <telerik:RadButton RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="NewRegistrationButton" runat="server"  OnClick="NewRegistrationButton_Click" Text="Create a new registration"></telerik:RadButton>
    </telerik:RadWizardStep>
</WizardSteps>
```

Please let me know if there is any way to reset the wizard.